# I have two Xcode projects, what is the easiest way to find out which two files are different in each?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, bash, command-line

I have the same Xcode project, but in different stages. For some reasons source control was not used on it (by programmer before me).

They are from different forks and they went two separate ways. Some files have different changes.

I have a task to merge these into one codebase and resolve conflicts. There are many files that are common among codebases, I think around 80%.

What is the easiest/fastest way to find out which files have differences between versions so I could actually work on them?

I tried using diff tool and go one by one, but there are probably close to a thousand files there.

Comment: You know diff can work on entire directories recursively, right? (Also, away from the command line, [Kaleidoscope](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com) is pretty cool and has a 15-day free trial.)

Comment: @MattGibson no, I use some proprietary graphical diff, how do I make this in diff? yeah exatly I use Kaleidoscope

Comment: Well, basically `diff -r OneProjectDir AnotherProjectDir` will do a recursive diff of the two directories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use FileMerge for the same purposes. You can find it at XCode -> Open Developer Tool -> FileMerge.

There is intuitive interface. Just drag-n-drop folders to Left and Right panels and press Compare. It will show you list of files that differ. Double click on text files to see compariso

Answer (score 1):

You can commit source files in the first project into a source version control system, like cvs or git, and then replace the source files with those in the second project.  Then, you will be able to see the differences between two projects by using the built-in diff functions.

Comment: But you won't be in a very useful place having done this.  Better is to use a graphical, recursive, diff tool.

Comment: I do personally not prefer to use graphic tools.  I actually wrote a very simple tool in Python to compare two source trees recursively.  It runs very efficiently as I use the following strategy:
1) compare size
2) if their sizes are the same, compare md5 hash
3) if their sizes or md5 hash values are different, do diff

Comment: In the way I described above, the binary files can also be properly dealt with, if you have some binary files in the source tree, such as libs.